# Glitches in Blender

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I had graphical glitches in Blender. Please help!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When the interface breaks like that it is likely because of an issue with the drivers for the Graphics Card.

Comment: I already tried reinstalling the video driver, nothing helped. Glitch appeared after reinstalling Windows 10

Comment: Try the Tripple Buffer.  File > User Preferences > System, and under the Window Draw Method title select Triple Buffer and then press Save User Settings

Comment: It didn't help.